# Join sql table on Datename

Tags: sql-server

I have a select statements which looks like

```
 Select  Count(*) as 'total', DATENAME(DW, [CALLSTART]) as 'TotalDayName' 
  into #totals
   From [WAREHOUSE].[DBO].[VOICE] WITH (NOLOCK) 


SELECT  DATENAME(DW, [CALLSTART]) AS 'DAY1'   
  FROM [WAREHOUSE].[DBO].[CALLS] ref WITH (NOLOCK)
  join #totals total on **ref.DAY1**  = total.TotalDayName
```

I have simplified the query for this question. Basically I need to join `#totals` with `Calls` table on `TotalDayName = ref.DAY1`. 
I know you can't use alias to join the table. I have tried `TotalDayName = ref.DATENAME(DW, [CALLSTART])` which gives me an error as well.

Comment: care to share the error?

Comment: *I know you can't use alias to join the table.*? Also, what error?

Comment: Why `ref.DATENAME(...)`? Shouldn't it be `DATENAME(DW, ref.[CALLSTART])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've just got your syntax wrong, you said

> I have tried `TotalDayName = ref.DATENAME(DW, [CALLSTART])`

But that should have been

```
TotalDayName = DATENAME(DW, ref.[CALLSTART])
```

It should work fine

Comment: That worked great. Thanks